# finding limit point of of the set $K=\{1/n \mid n\in \Bbb Z_+\}$?

Tags: general-topology

Determining the limit point of  $K=\{1/n \mid n\in \Bbb Z_+\}$ under the upper-limit topology $(a,b]$  on $\mathbb{R}$.

As limit point definition says if $A$ is a Subset of $X$ then the point $x$ in the topological space $X$ is said to be limit point of $A$ if the neighbourhood of $x$ intersects with $A$ other than $x$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be thorough you have to check all points of the reals whether they are limit points or not. However here are just a few cases: if $x > 0$, then there is some $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $\frac{1}{n} < x$. So $O_x = (\frac{1}{N}, x]$ only contains (possibly) $\{ \frac{1}{k}: k < N \}$, which is a finite set. So we can shrink $O_x$ to a smaller $(y,x]$ if needed to avoid all those finitely many points (except possibly $x$, if $x$ happens to be in $K$). So $x > 0$ is *not* a limit point.

And $x \le 0$ is also not a limit point, as $(x-1,x]$ misses $K$ entirely.

Comment: What is $N$ here ? Integer @Henno Brandsma

Comment: Yes, some integer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no limit points in this topology of this set. The only one candidate is $0$.  But for each neighborhood of $0$ of type: $U := (a, 0], a<0$ , $U \cap K = \emptyset$.

Comment: how to approach the problem @ninjaaa

Comment: i's commonly known fact that $0$ is limit point of sets like $K$ in euclidean topology.

Comment: it would be more helpful if you tell the approach as it will help me in all problems thanks @ninjaaa